# PLSQL archiving LONG datatype, error:

Tags: sql, plsql, insert, oracle11g, archive

Im using Oracle 11g, attempting to move anything older than 90days to the History table using PL/SQL..BUT i have one of the columns using datatype of LONG. So i have found the SQL that i thought should work but it gives errors:

```
    BEGIN
FOR ROW IN
       (SELECT  MESSSAGE_KEY,
          DISTRIBUTION_ID,
          MESSAGE,
          SYSTEM_NAME,
          MESSAGE_TYPE,
          MESSAGE_NAME,
          MESSAGE_STATUS,
          LATEST_INBOUND,
          CREATETS,
          MODIFYTS,
          CREATEUSERID,
          MODIFYUSERID,
          CREATEPROGID,
          MODIFYPROGID,
          LOCKID,
          ENTITY_KEY,
          ENTITY_NAME,
          ENTITY_VALUE
        FROM    NWCG_INBOUND_MESSAGE
        WHERE   TO_CHAR (createts, 'YYYYMMDD') >= TO_CHAR ((sysdate-90), 'YYYYMMDD')
    )
    LOOP
    INSERT INTO NWCG_INBOUND_MESSAGE_H
    VALUES (    
                ROW.MESSSAGE_KEY,
          ROW.DISTRIBUTION_ID,
          ROW.MESSAGE,
          ROW.SYSTEM_NAME,
          ROW.MESSAGE_TYPE,
          ROW.MESSAGE_NAME,
          ROW.MESSAGE_STATUS,
          ROW.LATEST_INBOUND,
          ROW.CREATETS,
          ROW.MODIFYTS,
          ROW.CREATEUSERID,
          ROW.MODIFYUSERID,
          ROW.CREATEPROGID,
          ROW.MODIFYPROGID,
          ROW.LOCKID,
          ROW.ENTITY_KEY,
          ROW.ENTITY_NAME,
          ROW.ENTITY_VALUE
           );
END LOOP;
END;
```

This is the error i am getting:

```
Error report:
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
ORA-06512: at line 2
06502. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

From my research it looks like this error has been about a lot, but i cant find any of peoples solutions to work.... any ideas?

Comment: I can see that i wrote "TO_CHAR (createts, 'YYYYMMDD') >= TO_CHAR ((.." this was just for testing as i didnt want to spend too long running selecting years of data

Comment: Why are you using a loop? You can do that with a single `INSERT ... SELECT ` statement which is most definitely a lot faster than a PL/SQL loop. Btw: the `LONG` data type has been deprecated since Oracle 9 came out. Why are you still using it?

Comment: It is the datatype that the table has been since created..i could check with the DBA to change to a BLOB, but are there any issue changing datatypes of columns if the table already contains data.....ive only a years experience so havent came across a lot of these situations yet..

Comment: Also i couldnt use the `INSERT ... SELECT` because of this `LONG` datatype

Comment: You can't convert the column directly, you need to add a new one (defined as `BLOB`) then update the column and drop the old one. You should *really* consider changing it as soon as possible

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name , Im waiting to hear back from dba about changing column datatype.... but would you know why i am getting this error? when i put the **WHERE** clause as `WHERE MESSSAGE_KEY ='2131'` it inserts the record to the table even with LONG type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The long datatype has been one of the reasons why I've always advised against storing documents or long string in an Oracle database. Without reverting to C and OCI, it is hard to use.

Now we have clob and blob which are reasonable usable in PL/SQL and SQL. But there are still many occurrences of the LONG datatype to be found of it, also in the Oracle data dictionary. Especially in XXX_VIEWS (user_views, all_views, dba_views) it is a real problem. Maybe the original developer should have named it UNUSABLE :-).

There is a workaround when the LONG contents are smaller than 32 KB; for full functionality I would recommend migrating to CLOB or using C. Good luck!

```
--
-- This sample code works when the long is smaller than 32 KB.
-- It is known to work on 9i, 10g, 11g r1, 11g r2, but it assumes
-- that a LONG smaller than 32 KB can be put in a PL/SQL variable.
-- And then cast.
--
-- You might want to add an exception handler to handle exceptions
-- when the size is larger than 32 KB. In this sample, this situation
-- can not occur; the where clause with text_length ensures that.
--
declare
  l_text_as_long  long;
  l_text_as_clob  clob;
  l_text_length   user_views.text_length%type;
begin
  select viw.text
  ,      viw.text_length
  into   l_text_as_long
  ,      l_text_length
  from   user_views viw
  where  viw.view_name = upper(l_object_name)
  and    viw.text_length <= 32767 /* To fix a problem when accessing a view that is larger than 32K, we have this condition. */
  ;
  l_text_as_clob := cast(l_text_as_long as clob);
  ... do something interesting ...
end;
```